# "Undefined index" error for field which is defined

Tags: views, entities, theming

I'm getting a strange error on a Views page, even though the page works. I get ten instances of this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: field_video in include() (line 28 of 
/path/to/drupal/sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/
views-view-fields--screenings--panel-pane.tpl.php).

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 28 of 
/path/to/drupal/sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/
views-view-fields--screenings--panel-pane.tpl.php).
```

Here's the content of line 28:

```
if (preg_match('/media/', $fields['field_video']->content)) {
    unset($fields['field_featured_image']);
}
```

The idea is that if a node of the relevant content type has both a Video and a Featured Image, the view will drop the image and replace it with the video.

What's crazy is that the page renders just fine; the image disappears when the node has content in both fields. What's even *crazier* is that the error appeared after a minor tweak to the above code, so I reverted my change and *it still throws this error*, no matter how many times I flush my caches.

What is happening here? This very same code worked fine for a long time, but now I can't seem to get rid of this error!

Comment: do you have any content without a field_video? if even one content didn't, it could cause this error. usually this is mitigated by adding a if(isset($fields['field_video'}) in the if statement

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note is you're seeing *notices*, not errors. Notices are a less severe [type of PHP error](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php). It's an alert that notes script execution is continuing, but something is wrong that could be a bigger problem. In your case, the array element `$fields['field_video']` doesn't exist,
thus trying reference a property `$fields['field_video']->content` on a non-existant object causes PHP to fire off notices.

As Geoff mentioned, this can occur if your view rows are loading nodes that don't produce this field and throwing an `isset($fields['field_video']) &&` in your if statement should fix your template from making bad references.